# Android + jfreeSVG: inheritance issues

Tags: java, android, svg

I'm developing and Android App with Android Studio. This app makes use of an all-java library module. I've included [jfreesvg](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) by adding `compile 'org.jfree:jfreesvg:3.1'` to the dependencies of said java library module.

Within that java library, I am trying the given example from the main [doc](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/javadoc/) for `SVGGraphics2D`:

```java
    SVGGraphics2D g2 = new SVGGraphics2D(300, 200);
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    g2.draw(new Rectangle(10, 10, 280, 180));
    String svgElement = g2.getSVGElement();
```

However, I get two compile errors in Android Studio, the first being in the second line:
`setPaint(java.awt.Paint) in SVGGraphics2D cannot be applied to (java.awt.Color)`

Also, in the next line, the following error with, I suppose the same cause, occurrs: `draw(java.awt.Paint) in SVGGraphics2D cannot be applied to (java.awt.Color)`

My question now is: Even though [java.awt.Paint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) is an Interface and [java.awt.Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) is an implementation of that interface, why do I get that error (and the same for [java.awt.Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) and [java.awt.Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html))?

For the sake of completion: If I do run the app, which I'm confused about that it works, I get the following Exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: [package].app, PID: 19596
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jfree/graphics2d/svg/SVGGraphics2D;
   at [package].[some.package].someMethod(Unknown)
   at [package].app.MainActivity$SomeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
   at [package].app.MainActivity$SomeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGGraphics2D" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/[package].app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/[package].app-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at [package].[some.package].someMethod(Unknown) 
   at [package].app.MainActivity$SomeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67) 
   at [package].app.MainActivity$SomeTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:62) 
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;
   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
   at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222)
   at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215)
   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:322)
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Graphics2D" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/[package].app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/[package].app-2, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        ... 16 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.awt.Graphics2D
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Ljava/awt/Graphics2D;" not found
            ... 21 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGGraphics2D
   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class "Lorg/jfree/graphics2d/svg/SVGGraphics2D;" not found
        ... 14 more
```

(I edited the stack trace for better readability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.awt.*` package is not available in Android.  So the library that you are trying to use cannot be used directly in your Android app.  At least not without further work.

You would need to implement those classes yourself, or source them from somewhere else, such as from the Apache Harmony project.